# Excel - Rounding Date and Time - Up or Down to the Hour

Tags: excel

I need to round date and time up and down to the hour in Excel.

The MROUND formula only does it to the nearest hour, but in the case of 10/05/2016 09:43 I want it to be rounded down to 10/05/2016 9:00 and in some cases I want to round up too.

It's essential that they stay in the format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(A1*24,0)/24

=ROUNDUP(A1*24,0)/24
```

Then you can set any datetime format you need using Cell/Format.

Comment: Also `FLOOR` is a possibility; )